# Infinite scrolling using "useInView()" doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing an app that fetches data about crypto coins. When the user reaches the last table row, it's supposed to fetch the next 20 coins from the API. I tried this with a normal button and it works normally.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useInfiniteQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';
import Axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

function App() {

    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

    const {
        data,
        fetchNextPage,
        hasNextPage,
        isFetchingNextPage,
        isLoading
    } = useInfiniteQuery({
        queryKey: ["coins"],
        queryFn: async({ pageParam = 1}) => {
            try {
                const response = await Axios.get(
                    `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets`, {
                        params: {
                            vs_currency: 'usd',
                            per_page: 20,
                            page: pageParam,
                            price_change_percentage: '24h'
                        },
                        headers: {
                            'x-cg-demo-api-key': "xoxo"
                        }
                    }
                );
                return response.data;
            } catch(error) {
                setIsError(true);
                throw error;
            };
        },
        getNextPageParam: (lastPage, allPages) => {
            return lastPage.length === 20 ? allPages.length + 1 : undefined;
        },
        enabled: !isError,
    });

    const [lastCoinRef, inView] = useInView();
    useEffect(() => {
        if(inView && hasNextPage && !isFetchingNextPage) {
            fetchNextPage();
        };
    }, [fetchNextPage, inView, hasNextPage, isFetchingNextPage]);

    
    if(isLoading) {return <>Loading...</>};
    if(isError) {return <>Error Loading</>};

    return(
        <>
            <header className="web-header">Cryptocurrency Tracker</header>

            <div className="table-coins-wrapper">
                <table className="table-coins">
                    <thead>
                        <tr className="table-headers">
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>24h</th>
                            <th className="hide-mobile">Volume</th>
                            <th className="hide-mobile">Market Cap</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                        data?.pages.flatMap((page) => 
                            page.map((coin) => {
                                let sign = "";
                                let classColor = "negative-change";
                                if(coin.price_change_percentage_24h >= 0) {
                                    sign = "+";
                                    classColor = "positive-change";
                                }
                                return(
                                    <tr className="coin-row" key={coin.market_cap_rank}>
                                        <td className="coin-info">{coin.market_cap_rank}</td>
                                        <td className="coin-info coin-image-name">
                                            {<img className="coin-image" src={coin.image}></img>}
                                            {coin.symbol.toUpperCase()}
                                        </td>
                                        <td className="coin-info">$ {coin.current_price.toLocaleString('en-US')}</td>
                                        <td className={"coin-info"}>
                                            <div className={`${classColor}`}>
                                                {sign}{coin.price_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)}%
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td className="coin-info hide-mobile">$ {coin.total_volume.toLocaleString('en-US')}</td>
                                        <td className="coin-info hide-mobile">$ {coin.market_cap.toLocaleString('en-US')}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                );
                            })
                        )
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Please excuse the messy code. I'm still a newbie and it's more fun for me to keep all of my supposed components in a single one. Thank you

Comment: Watched a video and saw that I forgot to add <div ref={lastCoinRef}></div> at the end of my table. :)